# Obtain indices of a factor of characters with names contained in a character vector

Tags: r

I have a factor of characters, let's say:

```
A <- factor(c(rep("home", times=5), rep("work", times=3), rep("hobby", times=7), rep("friends", times=10)))
```

and I would like to get the indices of the characters equal to the ones contained in another vector, say:

```
B <- c("work", "hobby")
```

in this case I would like to obtain the vector `6:15`. 
I tried with `which(A==B)` but it does not work...

Any idea?

Comment: You need `%in%` ie. `which(A %in% B)`

Comment: Thanks akrun... If you post it as an answer I can accept it as the one solving my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As akrun pointed out `%in%` should do the trick. Gives the output as:

```
[1] 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```